# Get the id when inserted or selected

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-insert

I want to fill the value of product_id. If article_code is not in the table, it executes the insert, but if record exists I don't know how to select the id of that record and assign to product_id.

The table "core_product" looks like that:

- id
- article_code

Here the code (inside of  a function):

```
DECLARE
    product_id int;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO core_product(article_code) 
        SELECT NEW.article_code
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT id INTO product_id
            FROM core_product
            WHERE article_code = NEW.article_code
        )
        RETURNING id INTO product_id;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a special variable [FOUND](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS):

```
DECLARE
    product_id int;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO product_id
    FROM core_product
    WHERE article_code = NEW.article_code;

    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO core_product(article_code) 
        SELECT NEW.article_code
        RETURNING id INTO product_id;
    END IF;
END
```

---

If there is an unique constraint on `article_code`, you can harden the function against a race condition using *retry loop* (as Craig suggested in a comment):

```
BEGIN
    LOOP
        SELECT id INTO product_id
        FROM core_product
        WHERE article_code = NEW.article_code;

        IF FOUND THEN
            EXIT; -- exit loop
        END IF;

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO core_product(article_code) 
            SELECT NEW.article_code
            RETURNING id INTO product_id;
            EXIT; -- exit loop

        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            -- do nothing, go to the beginning of the loop
            -- and check once more if article_code exists
        END;
    END LOOP;
    -- do something with product_id
END;
```

Comment: ... and before anyone asks, doing this as two statements instead of one like the original question doesn't change its concurrency properties significantly. The original is prone to a race condition that means it can still fail with a unique violation or insert a duplicate if there's no unique constraint. The version klin posted has the same race condition. The only way to avoid it use to use `insert ... on conflict ...` (from PostgreSQL 9.5), lock the table in exclusive mode for the insert, or use a retry loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/398670